# How do I delete the lates values in a range that I have copy pasted using a VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Below is my code for Copy Pasting values within a range to another sheet. But I was wondering, now that I have copy and pasted the values, how do I create a macro that always deletes the latest range of values that I have pasted?

(Or if possible, how do I create a macro where I can select which range of values that I want to delete?)

Btw, (`"bookmark"`) is the range of values from `E6:P6` in the sheet I'm copying the values from.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

```
Sub AddBookmark()

    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Bookmark").Copy

    Worksheets("Bookmarks").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Bookmarks").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-18, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your `Bookmark` range is 1 row by 12 columns (i.e. `E6:P6`) then your current code is writing to columns `A:L` in a row 4 rows below the previously written row.  So to delete the latest entries that you have created, you just need to find the last non-empty cell in column A of `Worksheets("Bookmarks")` and delete columns `A:L` of that row.

So

```
Sub DeleteBookmark()
    With Worksheets("Bookmarks")
        .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 12).Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

---

P.S. Please note, in the above code, the qualification of `Rows.Count` with the worksheet it is referring to.  In your existing code you are not doing that, which can cause errors in certain circumstances.  Your code should use, for example,

```
Worksheets("Bookmarks").Cells(Worksheets("Bookmarks").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

---

P.P.S.  I'm not sure why your code is offsetting the last cell by -18 rows when doing the PasteFormats.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! It works, but it only deletes the latest row, how do I change it so it deletes the latest 19 rows?

Comment: Your question says you are only copying E6:P6 (i.e. 1 row x 11 columns) to the "Bookmarks" worksheet each time you run your `AddBookmark` macro.  Why do you want to remove 19 rows in the `DeleteBookmark` macro?  (FWIW - `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-18, 0).Resize(19, 12).Clear` would do it, but I just don't understand **why** you want to do it.)